# how to make live rtsp player using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, live

I am creating an rtsp live viewer using ffmpeg. I have a question about video delay, so I ask.

At beginning play live rtsp, Video delay is about 2 seconds on general movie player(vlc, gom). However, when the playback speed is increased, the delay is reduced and the video delay is shortened to about 300 ms.

I do not know how to reduce the delay to speed up or speed up this playback on my ffmpeg player.

It seems like I can use something like av_seek_frame, but it does not work.
How can I reduce live rtsp video delay with ffmpeg?

In summary, I'd like to get the latest frame to be av_read_frame in live rtsp.

Comment: Does your player synchronize frames to a timestamp or synchronize video frames to audio frames?

Comment: If it draws the frames as soon as it receives them, the delay you are experiencing is probably network delay